# Download an image from the web and store in media library (windows phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i am trying to download an image from the web  save it in the media library , below is my code, am i missing something here, Thanks in advance

```
  public void storePicture()
    {
        try
        {


            using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {

                 string url = @"http://mynokiablog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/wp8.jpeg";

                  BitmapImage storeimage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));

                  // height and width are 0 
                  int testheight = storeimage.PixelHeight;
                  int testwidth = storeimage.PixelWidth;
                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("testname");
                  // NullRefrenceException
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(storeimage);

                wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
                fileStream.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
               System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add event handler as below

```
    storeimage.ImageOpened += bitmapImage_ImageOpened;
    storeimage.ImageFailed += bitmapImage_ImageFailed;
    storeimage.DownloadProgress += bitmapImage_DownloadProgress;
```

then in `bitmapImage_DownloadProgress,` create `WritableBitMap` and save

Answer (score 3):

```
private void LoadIMG()
    {

        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };


        bitmapImage.ImageOpened += bitmapImage_ImageOpened;
        bitmapImage.ImageFailed += bitmapImage_ImageFailed;
        bitmapImage.DownloadProgress += bitmapImage_DownloadProgress;
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes///Site-16990/Type-0/7b912e70-352a-454f-8ea7-5d5ecd6ebfae.gif");
    }

    private void bitmapImage_DownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bitmapImage_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void bitmapImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var userStoreForApplication = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); 
         var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(sender as BitmapImage);
         var isolatedStorageFileStream = userStoreForApplication.CreateFile("Myfile.gif");
         writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(isolatedStorageFileStream, writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 85); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it: http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/02/how-to-download-and-save-images-in-wp7.html#.TzUtWBSaLkM.twitter

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi lumen i did not want  to use webclient, i have posted the solution with  BitmapImage